# haskell list character frequenceies

Tags: list, haskell

I am having trouble with an assignment question!

Write the function

```
freq2 :: String -> -> [(Int,[Char])]
```

Like `freq`, the function `freq2` counts frequency of occurrence of alphabetic characters.

Given the string:

We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness

I need to end up with:

```
[(1,"qv"), (2,"gm"), (3,"cfpwy"), (4,"b"), (5,"u"), (6,"do"),(8,"s"), (9,"ln"), (10,"i"), (12,"r"), (13,"h"), (16,"a"),(22,"t"), (28,"e")]
```

So far I can get to:

```
[('q',1),('v',1),('g',2),('m',2),('c',3),('f',3),('p',3),('w',3),('y',3),('b',4),('u',5),('d',6),('o',6),('s',8),('l',9),('n',9),('i',10),('r',12),('h',13),('a',16),('t',22),('e',28)]
```

Using:

```
 freq2 :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
 freq2 input = result2
    where
    lower_case_list = L.map C.toLower input
    filtered_list = L.filter C.isAlpha lower_case_list
    result = L.map (\a -> (L.head a, L.length a)) $ L.group $ sort filtered_list
    result2 = sortBy (compare `on` snd) result
```

Is there an easy way to get to the last stage or to do the whole thing, possibly using library functions? Or can you please provide some direction on how to finish off this question?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at `groupBy`.

Comment: They teach haskell in schools? Which school, if I may ask?

Comment: I would not call it teaching when you have to resort to searching google for hours, so you can hopefully find answers. Last time I looked, teaching was actually showing you how to do something, not just giving you the very basics and then a link to the haskell website, saying to use library functions that you may find there. The school is University of Southern Queensland!

Comment: I did try groupBy

It creates a list with sub lists, so to display the results I have to modify the function definition, which is not allowed!
Output:
[[('q',1),('v',1)],[('g',2),('m',2)],[('c',3),('f',3),('p',3),('w',3),('y',3)],[('b',4)],[('u',5)],[('d',6),('o',6)],[('s',8)],[('l',9),('n',9)],[('i',10)],[('r',12)],[('h',13)],[('a',16)],[('t',22)],[('e',28)]]

Comment: Ok now you have a list made up of lists. An inner list looks like `[('q',1),('v',1)]`. Can you convert this to `(1, "qv")`? Note a string is a list of chars.

Comment: That is why I asked this question here. I have no idea at this stage, without spending many hours more researching to see what I can find that will do the conversion. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to finish it off!

Comment: You already know all the needed functions and techniques. Try `map fst` on an inner list, it should get you "qv". Try also `snd . head` on the same list. Combine the two to get `(1, "qv")`. Finally take the function you have just composed and `map` it through the outer list.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this appended to your solution should work:

```
result3 = map (\xs@((_,x):_) -> (x,  map fst xs)) $ L.groupBy ((==) `on` snd) result2
```

My preference would be to use a Map for these types of problems though:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.Char as C
import qualified Data.Tuple as T

string = filter C.isAlpha $ map C.toLower "We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness"

swapMapWith f = Map.fromListWith f . map T.swap . Map.toList

freq2 :: String -> [(Int, String)]
freq2 = Map.toList . swapMapWith (++) . foldl (\agg c -> Map.insertWith (+) [c] 1 agg) Map.empty
```

Comment: Thanks but neither of those give me the answer. The result3 one creates a list with the values in the wrong order. And not knowing much about haskell as yet I am unable to figure out how to reverse these. I need the number first and the char last eg: (1,"qv")

Comment: The function that you gave had errors that after fixing, I did get it to load and compile. But then it gave an error message when I tried to run it. 
<interactive>:75:1:
    No instance for (Show (String -> [(Int, String)]))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Show (String -> [(Int, String)]))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

1. import needed modules

   ```
   import Data.Char
   import Data.List
   ```
2. filter out uninterested characters and convert the rest to lower case

   ```
   toLowerAlpha :: String -> String
   toLowerAlpha = map toLower . filter isAlpha
   ```
3. `sort` first, then `group`, after that the length of each group is the frequency of character in that group

   ```
   elemFreq :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
   elemFreq = map (\l -> (length l, head l)) . group . sort
   ```
4. sort and group as step 2, but according to frequency at here, then combine all those characters that have the same frequencies

   ```
   groupByFreq :: (Integral a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [[(a, b)]]
   groupByFreq = groupBy (onFreq (==)) . sortBy (onFreq compare)
       where onFreq op (f1,_) (f2,_) = op f1 f2

   collectByFreq :: (Integral a) => [[(a, b)]] -> [(a, [b])]
   collectByFreq = map (\ls -> (fst . head $ ls, map snd ls))
   ```
5. sequence the above functions will give the required function

   ```
   freq2 = collectByFreq . groupByFreq . elemFreq . toLowerAlpha
   ```

---

Method 2:

1. import needed modules

   ```
   import qualified Data.Char as Char
   import qualified Data.Map as Map
   ```
2. filter out uninterested characters and convert the rest to lower case

   toLowerAlpha :: String -> String
   toLowerAlpha = map Char.toLower . filter Char.isAlpha
3. create a map, key and value are character and corresponding frequency, respectively

   ```
   toFreqMap :: (Ord a, Num b) => [a] -> Map.Map a b
   toFreqMap = foldr (\c -> Map.insertWith (+) c 1) Map.empty
   ```
4. convert the map created in step 2 to another map, using frequency as key, and characters have that frequency as value

   ```
   toFreqCol :: (Ord a, Ord b) => Map.Map a b -> Map.Map b [a]
   toFreqCol = Map.foldrWithKey (\k a m -> Map.insertWith (++) a [k] m) Map.empty
   ```
5. sequence the above functions will give the required function

   ```
   freq2 = Map.toAscList . toFreqCol . toFreqMap . toLowerAlpha
   ```

Comment: Thanks, having seen it done, I now have an understanding of what is required. I was thinking I would need to use a couple of map functions at the same time but was not sure how to go about it. Now I just need to make it work with the function definition that I need to use: freq2 :: String -> [(Char,Int)]